# How to transcode HDR to SDR in Windows MediaTranscoder API?

Tags: windows, encoding, uwp, transcoding, transcode

**How to transcode HDR to SDR in Windows MediaTranscoder API?**

Windows provides [MediaTranscoder API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files) to transcode video. I am trying to transcode HDR (High Dynamic Range) video into SDR (Standard Dynamic Range) video. I see there is an API for [setting video quality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.videoencodingquality?view=winrt-22000) i.e.

```
MediaEncodingProfile profile =
    MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);
```

However, there is no way to set bit-depth. Any idea how can I change target bit-depth of the video?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do that using UWP APIs, you might need to check Media Foundation API for this.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT could you please be specific which media foundation API can I use?

Comment: I have to say I'm not familiar with Media Foundation API so I can't tell which API should be used in your scenario. You might ask another question with ms-media-foundation tag